# Jquery .animate 100% height not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, height, joomla3.0

My developer and I are stuck with a drop down lead form using Jquery.

http://nextinlinefilms.com.au/index.php here is the link.

It is the "make an enquiry today" part when you click the open tab the .animate isnt working.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery( ".jscript" ).click(function() {
 jQuery( ".enquiry" ).animate({height: "100%"},1000);
});

jQuery( ".jscript2" ).click(function() {
 jQuery( ".enquiry" ).animate({height: "255px"},1000);
 });
```

Please help we are not sure. You can use px but on phones and other screen sizes it needs a smaller or larger px height. Auto doesnt work either.

The close button works fine as it has a px height that is needed.

Comment: Im not sure how to use that site sorry im not the developer.

Comment: try making the div with `class="enquiry"` to be of `position:relative;`

Comment: Tried this thank you but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done this in another way, I suggest that:

`<div class="b2j-contact-group-class"></div>` which contains the actual form elements, gets a `display: none;` by default, then when you click on `.jscript`, you can do this:

`JQuery(".bj2-contact-group-class").slideDown(1000);`

And to close it:

`JQuery(".bj2-contact-group-class").slideUp(1000);`

You should get the nice effect that your looking for, it's much better than playing around with a parent element height.

Comment: I just tried this and I must of did it wrong so this is the code.

Comment: jQuery( ".jscript" ).click(function() {
    JQuery(".bj2-contact-group-class").slideDown(1000);
  
     });
    jQuery( ".jscript2" ).click(function() {JQuery(".bj2-contact-group-class").slideUp(1000);
  
 });

Comment: jQuery( ".jscript" ).click(function() {
    JQuery(".bj2-contact-group-class").slideDown(1000);
  
    });
    jQuery( ".jscript2" ).click(function() {
    JQuery(".bj2-contact-group-class").slideUp(1000);
  
    });

Comment: sorry first time using this site.

Comment: No its not doing any thing anymore.

Comment: @CraigFrankham forget the `display: none;` try to run this code when the page is loading, then test if the other code works: `jQuery('.bj2-contact-group-class').hide();`

Comment: sorry not sure what you mean I dont think the code is working at all I am using Joomla 3.0 if that means anything .animate was working except for the 100% height issue.

Comment: @CraigFrankham you can get the slide effect with your code, but you have to change the `100%` to some pixel value (you have to estimate it), it will work, but I don't like it `:D`, you can try like `700px` instead of `100%`.

Comment: Yeah we need it to be a percentage or a different way as for mobiles and tablets its a different height. I will check with the developer thanks again. maybe he can get your way working :) thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Though I can't test this with adjustments in web developer tools, there's one adjustment why it won't work - in your template.css on line 163 you have set

```
.b2j_form {
    height: 14% !important;
}
```

Therefore the form will never display with the height 100% that the animate function writes as inline style to the form, because the !important will always override the height 100%.

Note - I'm not sure if this applies to this variation of the question as I was just about to post this on a similar question for the same problem that you deleted some seconds before I was about to post.